# Login Form Not Working?

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to migrate my application from the `mysql_*` Functions over to the `PDO API` and my login box which was working; has stopped Forwarding the details onto the `user_check.php` file..

My Code is as followed:

```
<?php
session_start();


if (isset($_SESSION['real_name'])){

include "member_area.php";
die("-");

}
include "Database.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_002.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Billing Area</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tooltip.css" type="text/css">

<div id="indexcpcenter">
 <div class="indexcpcenterbox">

   <form method="post" action="user_check.php">
Member Login <Br>
Email Address:<br>
<input type="text" name="username" type="text">
<br>
Password:<br><input type="password" name="password" type="text"></td>
<br><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
<br><i>Produced By <a href="http://www.slayer-productions.com">Slayer-Productions</a> Copyright 2012-2015 Slayer-Productions.com
</form>

</div>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slideshow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tooltip.js"></script>
 <div style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; top: 384px; left: 351.5px;" id="popup"><div id="popup_title"></div><div id="popup_body">Seems like this was empty</div> <div id="popup_bottom"></div></div>

 <div id="dp_swf_engine"><object style="position: absolute; top: -1000000px; left: -1000000px;" id="_dp_swf_engine" data="swf/dealply_swf_engine.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="1" width="1"><param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess"></object></div>

 </body></html>
```

an easier readable version is available here: http://pastebin.com/5GQ8Nnud

I have no idea why it's not forwarding details onto the `user_check.php` file, does anyone have ideas?

**As Requested: Database.php**

```
$hostname = "mysql:dbname=alltables;host=127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "xxx";

try
{
    $Con = new PDO ($hostname, $username, $password);
}catch (PDOException $e){
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: you were talking about migration from mysql_* to PDO, but there's no code of that! Share code of `Database.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my `member_area.php` file. The original contents of the file was:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_002.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Billing Area</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tooltip.css" type="text/css">

Success!

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slideshow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tooltip.js"></script>
 <div style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; top: 384px; left: 351.5px;" id="popup"><div id="popup_title"></div><div id="popup_body">Seems like this was empty</div> <div id="popup_bottom"></div></div>

 <div id="dp_swf_engine"><object style="position: absolute; top: -1000000px; left: -1000000px;" id="_dp_swf_engine" data="swf/dealply_swf_engine.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="1" width="1"><param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess"></object></div>

 </body></html>
```

I changed said file, to just `success`  and the re-direct from the `index.php` page worked. Strange!

Answer (score 0):

Is the POST data received by user_check.php ?

```
<pre>
print_r($_POST)
</pre>
```

If so what does the authentication class/file look like?

What did you already try?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UR5Fq60S <-- is the user_check.php file, I have found the problem to the question; it was a problem on `member_area.php` -- the new problem is that even if `$_SESSION['real_name'];` is registered. IT does not re-direct to `member_area.php`

Comment: We/I really need the code that does the authentication to see if there is a way to help you out.

Comment: @user1902584 can you update your question then? Also if you could put an edit on what the problem was in `member_area.php` that'd be nice for people who were curious.

Comment: It won't because of "Headers already sent". Make sure you have `error_reporing(E_ALL)` enabled

Comment: @metal_fan `error_reporting(E_ALL);` Shows no errors on the login page